# Can I make image behave as if it had a different height (different dimensions)?

Tags: html, css

I've got a bunch of divs that have an image and some text below that are using float:left to form a grid.
99% of the images are the same size (100x200 pixels), but the 1% (size 100x150 pixels) are causing problems, i.e. the float is causing them to mess up the "grid".

Is there any way I can make the smaller images act as if they are the same size as the larger ones and do it without stretching them? I'd like them to be centred vertically in the space that the larger ones would have taken (essentially a top and bottom margin of 25px).

I am currently using a separate min-height for the parent divs, depending on screen sizes, but that feels like a bad solution as the spacing between the rows is larger than I'd like for some screen sizes (I could add a bunch more, but as I said, a bad solution).

Comment: Use `display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:center; align-items:center;`

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly! I changed align-itmes to baseline, as that looks better for what I'm doing,  but other than that, perfect! If anyone else needs this, I added it to the parent div.